# Customize code folding in Atom editor

Tags: editor, atom-editor

Is it possible to customize the code folding behavior in the Atom editor? There are certain tags I want it to ignore, which it currently doesn't (e.g. #if def in Fortran)

Comment: Rather than set custom patterns to exclude form folding, I desperately want to be able to create arbitrary start and stop points for folding in Atom like you can in Espresso.

Comment: As far as creating arbitrary folding regions, there's a plugin that does that: https://atom.io/packages/custom-folds.